# Docker - run vncserver at container startup

Tags: docker, dockerfile

i've created a Dockerfile which is based on an Ubuntu base image, and my Dockerfile installs the various packages for X-Windows.

I run my container from the command line as so:
docker run -i -t mycontainer

Then i run the vncserver on the container as so:
docker exec [container_id] vncserver -geometry 1920x1080

My question: How can i ensure the vncserver is started up automatically when i start my container? I want to avoid issuing a separate command to start vncserver after running the container. If i try the following, the vncserver doesn't seem to be starting:
docker run -i -t mycontainer /bin/bash -c "vncserver -geometry 1920x1080"

the ENTRYPOINT on my Dockerfile is "/bin/bash"

thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Can you share the Dockerfile?  You should be able to specify the relevant command as a CMD in the Dockerfile; the way you describe your use of ENTRYPOINT, it's probably problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this in your dockerfile?

> ENTRYPOINT /path/to/vncserver -geometry 1920x1080 && /bin/bash